# Play audio-only file with subtitles, possibly use some still image as stub

Tags: linux, audio, subtitles, mplayer

Is it possible to make `mplayer` display subtitles while playing an audio-only file?

I've already tried:

```
mplayer filename.mp3 -sub filename.srt
```

but no luck - it just doesn't creates a viewport as soon as it sees that there is no video. `-vo x11` doesn't help either.

I know that I can convert my audio files to video files, or use some subtitle editing software such as AegiSub just for playing my files; but neither of these ways is convenient for me because I have a lot of audio files.

Answer (score 3):

## How can I play audio-only file with subtitles in `mplayer`?

If you're willing to be flexible on using an image as a stub and get `ffmpeg` involved in generating a placeholder, it can be done.

1. Create a blank file with `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -t 1500 -s 1024x768 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero silence.mpeg
   ```

   *(via [`ffmpeg-user`](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-October/002602.html))*

   `-s` can be whatever size you want the window

   `-t` should be **at least as long as your audio** in seconds, or the subtitles stop playing!
2. Play the blank video, while specifying what you *really* want to play and the subtitles using `-audiofile` and `-sub`, eg:

   ```
   mplayer silence.mpeg -sub subtitles.srt -audiofile audio.mp3
   ```
3. *(optional)* Tweak the video file in `1.` generated to be red, or blue, or a pattern, or whatever you'd like as a background.

#### See subtitles in action in `mplayer`:

[image: demo of mplayer]

Yes, I know you can't hear the audio in a .gif, but it does work!

### Alternative in `VLC`

If yo prefer (or don't have access to `ffmpeg`), `VLC` can handle audio and subtitles, eg:

```
vlc audio.file --sub-file subtitle_file.srt
```

But note that you [have to select a visualisation](https://possiblyusefulinfo.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/display-subtitles-to-audio-only-files-in-vlc/); as subtitles won't display over album art.

Or you can do it from the interface:

[image: demo]

<sup>*(credit to [Chris Zabriskie](http://chriszabriskie.com/preludes/) for [Prelude #4 from the Free Music Archive](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Chris_Zabriskie/Preludes/04_-_Prelude_No_4)... not that you can hear it in the gif)*</sup>

Comment: I tried optimizing empty video creation (it's still a dirty workaround but I didn't want to install any new software) and came up with this: `ffmpeg -t 3000 -s 1x1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -r 20 -i /dev/zero silence.ogv`. Unfortunately, subtitles don't show in time with frame rate being zero so I stopped on 20.

Comment: There is no `/dev/zero` in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I have accomplished this same task with [mpv](https://pkgs.org/download/mpv) in the past without needing the video file.  Use:

```
mpv --no-audio-display --force-window --sub-file="<subfile>" "<inputfile>"
```

I was making simple SRT subs for each song; 3 or 4 lines of lyric per, like:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Sample Text
Sample Text Here
Sample Text Here Again
```

Changing your start/stop times for how long to display, obviously. :)  Works great for karaoke from my laptop to this day.

Comment: Add `--sub-pos=50` to vertically center the subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an arbitrary image, just a solid black color, then there's no need to create a dummy video file: you can just reinterpret /dev/zero:

```
mplayer /dev/zero -rawvideo format=rgb24:pal:fps=20 -demuxer rawvideo \
        -audiofile filename.mp3 -sub filename.srt
```

By removing `format=rgb24:` the background can even be made green [#008800] (along with saving some percentage of CPU usage).
However, implementing an arbitrary-colored background is kind of problematic.
For instance, one can do it by feeding the color bytes through a pipe:

```
perl -e 'for (;;) {syswrite(STDOUT, "\x3F\x3F\x3F\x00" x (1024*1024*2))}' | \
  mplayer - -rawvideo format=rgb32:pal:fps=20 -demuxer rawvideo \
          -audiofile filename.mp3 -sub filename.srt
```

, but then the ability to rewind backwards is lost.
Another option is to use the geq video filter and specify a desired color in YUV space:

```
mplayer /dev/zero -rawvideo pal:fps=20 -demuxer rawvideo -vf geq=63:128:128 \
        -audiofile filename.mp3 -sub filename.srt
```

This way, rewinding backwards is working, but the CPU usage of playing grows noticeably higher.